# Turn off synchronous scrolling not caused by either scrollbind or diff

Tags: neovim, vimdiff, scrolling

I have a file that has decided to scroll synchronously when I open it in a second window and start scrolling. `scrollbind` and `diff` are set to `off`. (`:set scrollbind?` prints `noscrollbind` and `:set diff?` prints `nodiff`.)

What else can I try?

I'm using neovim.

Comment: what does the `scrollopt` say ?

Comment: `scrollopt=ver,jump`

Comment: try set it to null, `set scrollopt=`, maybe it will solve the issue...

Comment: @Nobe4 That didn't work. :-/

Comment: Another suggestion, how do you open the new file ? in the doc: `This option is mostly reset when splitting a window to edit another file.  This means that ":split | edit file" results in two windows with scroll-binding, but ":split file" does not.`

Comment: @Nobe4 I usually use `Ctrl-W v` so `:vsplit`.

Comment: `set cursorbind?`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt That was it!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As [Christian Brabandt suggested in a comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7450/turn-off-synchronous-scrolling-not-caused-by-either-scrollbind-or-diff#comment12220_7450), this can be caused by the `'cursorbind'` setting.

From `:help 'cursorbind'`:

> When this option is set, as the cursor in the current
>   window moves other cursorbound windows (windows that also have
>   this option set) move their cursors to the corresponding line and
>   column.

You can use `:verbose set cursorbind?` to find out what is switching this setting on.